# Como exibir uma imagem armazenada no campo BLOB do mysql em uma página php?

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho uma imagem salva no meu blob do mysql codificada na base 64. Porém, não consigo exibir a imagem em uma página php simples. Na realidade o que eu quero é que ao usuário clicar em uma categoria de produto, seja retornado uma pesquisa realizada no php que retorne os valores do campo e também as imagens de cada produto. Segue meu código php que está retornando uma imagem quebrada na minha página e não a imagem que está armazenada no meu banco de dados. Por favor, gostaria de encontrar onde está o erro no meu código.

```
    <?php

        require "conexao.php";

                    $sql = "SELECT * FROM produtos WHERE idProduto = 17;";

                    $result = mysqli_query($conexao, $sql) or die(mysql_error());  
                    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

                    echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' . base64_encode( $row['imagemProduto1'] ) . '" />';

        mysqli_close($conexao);
    ?>
```

Answer (score 4):

Encontrei o erro. não precisava decodificar de volta. A imagem já está vindo pronta para ser exibida.

Desta forma, a linha que estava assim:

```
 echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' . base64_encode( $row['imagemProduto1'] ) . '" />';
```

fica assim:

```
 echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' . $row['imagemProduto1'] . '" />';
```

Resolvido!

Comment: Tenho a impressão que você "resolveu" do lado errado. O ideal seria consertar o DB pra armazenar sem base64. Aliás, no seu caso, base64 é péssimo pra tudo. Só está gastando banda à toa. Seria mais sensato ter um PHP separado servindo a imagem original direto do DB, sem conversão.

Comment: É que estou trabalhando em um projeto multiplataforma e o meu parceiro que esta fazendo do outro lado necessita que os dados sejam armazenados desta forma.

Comment: Isso não me parece ter muito sentido: "necessita que os dados sejam armazenados desta forma", inclusive por base64 não ser formato de armazenagem, mas entendo que o projeto é seu, e você tem a liberdade de fazer como quiser. Só comentei pra não deixar de alertar para o problema da arquitetura, e para eventualmente outros leitores terem a oportunidade de ler o contraponto.