# Como exibir um campo do tipo BLOB do mySQL na página html

Tags: php, mysql, blob

Já procurei várias vez mas não encontrei uma solução, preciso exibir uma imagem que foi salva como BLOB no banco de dados.

Parte do código que salva no banco de dados e exibe os dados

```
function manage_report($param1 = '', $param2 = '', $param3 = '')
{
    if ($this->session->userdata('doctor_login') != 1)
        redirect(base_url() . 'index.php?login', 'refresh');

    if ($param1 == 'create') {

        $data['img_principal'] = $this->input->post('img_principal');

        $this->db->insert('report', $data);
        $this->session->set_flashdata('flash_message', get_phrase('report_created'));
        redirect(base_url() . 'index.php?doctor/manage_report', 'refresh');
    }
    if ($param1 == 'edit' && $param2 == 'do_update') {

        $data['img_principal'] = $this->input->post('img_principal');

        $this->db->where('report_id', $param3);
        $this->db->update('report', $data);
        $this->session->set_flashdata('flash_message', get_phrase('account_updated'));
        redirect(base_url() . 'index.php?doctor/manage_report', 'refresh');

    } else if ($param1 == 'edit') {
        $page_data['edit_profile'] = $this->db->get_where('report', array(
            'report_id' => $param2
        ))->result_array();
    } 

    $page_data['page_name']  = 'manage_report';
    $page_data['page_title'] = get_phrase('manage_report');
    $page_data['reports']    = $this->db->get('report')->result_array();
    $this->load->view('index', $page_data);
}
```

Como estou tentando mostrar na página .html

```
<img src="<?php echo $row['img_principal']; ?>"/>
```

banco de dados

```
CREATE TABLE `report` ( `report_id` int(11) NOT NULL, `img_principal` blo NOT NULL ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Comment: Teria como atualizar a postagem deixando clara a parte que recupera o BLOB, e o tipo de dados do campo? Se for imagem, precisa de um PHP separado para servi-la (e evitar gambiarras com base64, que só são boas para imagens pequenas)

Comment: Aqui tem uma idéia, mas sinceramente, as respostas em geral sobre esse assunto no site estão deixando a desejar: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/142841/70

Comment: Vou verificar @Bacco, obrigada!