# Como buscar uma imagem que está armazenada no banco de dados e exibí-la em um IMG do HTML?

Tags: php, html, jquery, mysql

Então, 
Eu estou fazendo uma página na qual o usuário faz o upload de uma imagem e ela é armazenada no banco de dados (MySQL). **Veja abaixo como ela fica armazenada no banco:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

- Até ai tudo bem. Agora eu gostaria de pegar essa imagem e exibir dentro de um **IMG**, no seu atributo src, da minha página html. **Veja abaixo:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

- Eu Gostaria de fazer uma requisição via AJAX que me retornasse essa imagem que está no banco de dados e colocasse ela dentro dessa **IMG** que eu destaquei na imagem acima. (**OBS**: Essa foto mostrada na imagem foi colocada diretamente no src de um IMG e ela está dentro de uma pasta).
- Se alguém tiver alguma sugestão de como fazer isso, eu ficaria agradecido. Não precisa postar códigos e códigos, é só uma luz de como fazer isso. (Estou usando jQuery, Ajax, PHP e MySQL).
- Obrigado! (Se precisarem de alguma parte do meu código, para elucidar a situação, é só avisarem. Não coloquei pra não deixar a pergunta muito extensa).

Atualizando: **Vou postar a parte do código no qual eu insiro a imagem (Juntamente com os dados do usuário) na tabela do banco de dados:**

```html
<?php

  function formularioPerfil($conecta)
 { 
    
  $usuario = $_SESSION['usuario'];
  $nome_completo = !empty($_POST["nome-completo"]) ? filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'nome-completo', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING) : "";  
  $frase = !empty($_POST["frase"]) ? filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'frase', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING) : "";   
  $email = !empty($_POST["email"]) ? filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING) : "";   
  $data_nascimento = !empty($_POST["data-nascimento"]) ? filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'data-nascimento', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING) : "";  
  $escolaridade = !empty($_POST["escolaridade"]) ? filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'escolaridade', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING) : "";   
  $cargo_atual = !empty($_POST["cargo-atual"]) ? filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'cargo-atual', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING) : "";  
  $biografia = !empty($_POST["biografia"]) ? filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'biografia', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING) : "";  
  
  $hoje = date('Y-m-d');    
  
  //SE HOUVER ARQUIVO, FAZ INSERÇÃO
  if(!empty($_FILES['imagem']['name']))
  {
   //UPLOAD DE ARQUIVO  VINDO DO FORMULÁRIO
   $files = $_FILES["imagem"];


   if($_FILES["imagem"]["error"][0] != 4)
   {
   
    $_verifica['tamanho'] = 1024 * 1024 * 2; // 2Mb 
    // Array com as extensões permitidas
    $_verifica['extensoes'] = array('jpg','jpeg','jpg','png');
    
      $file_tmp = $_FILES["imagem"]["tmp_name"]; //NOME DO ARQUIVO NO COMPUTADOR
      $file_name = $_FILES["imagem"]["name"];
      $file_size = $_FILES["imagem"]["size"]; 
      $file_type = $_FILES["imagem"]["type"];
      $partes = explode(".", $file_name);
      $extensao = end($partes);
      ////verificando a extensão.
      //$extensao = strtolower(end(explode('.', $_FILES['upload-file']['name'])));
      if (array_search($extensao, $_verifica['extensoes']) === false) {
       die('extensaoerrada');
      }
      // Faz a verificação do tamanho do arquivo
      else if ($_verifica['tamanho'] < $file_size) {
       die('tamanhomaiorqueopermitido');
      }        
      
      //Nomeando o arquivo que será armazenado
      $nome_do_arquivo_final = $hoje . "-" . str_replace(' ','-', $usuario) . '.' . $extensao;
      
      
      $binario = file_get_contents($file_tmp); // evitamos erro de sintaxe do MySQL
      $binario = mysqli_real_escape_string($conecta, $binario);
      //FIM DO UPLOAD DE ARQUIVO       
   }
   $update_usuario = "UPDATE tbl_usuarios SET nome_completo = '$nome_completo', data_nascimento = '$data_nascimento', escolaridade = '$escolaridade', cargo_atual = '$cargo_atual', biografia = '$biografia', frase_usuario = '$frase', email = '$email', imagem = '$binario', nome_imagem = '$nome_do_arquivo_final', tipo_imagem = '$file_type' WHERE usuario = '$usuario' AND funcionario = '$usuario'";
  }
  else
  {  
   $update_usuario = "UPDATE tbl_usuarios SET nome_completo = '$nome_completo', data_nascimento = '$data_nascimento', escolaridade = '$escolaridade', cargo_atual = '$cargo_atual', biografia = '$biografia', frase_usuario = '$frase', email = '$email' WHERE usuario = '$usuario' AND funcionario = '$usuario'";
  }   
   
   
  $result_update = mysqli_query($conecta, $update_usuario);  
  
  if($result_update)
  {
   echo "dadosalteradoscomsucesso";
   die();
  }
  else
  {
   mysqli_error($conecta);
   echo "erronoupdatedousuario";
   die();
  }  
   
 }

?>
```

Comment: Como assim Pendente ? O que eu poderia fazer pra melhorar essa pegunta ? Só se talvez eu postasse o código todo, coisa que eu acho desnecessário, devido a descrição da pergunta.

Comment: Veja se isso ajuda, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/142841/como-exibir-uma-imagem-armazenada-no-campo-blob-do-mysql-em-uma-página-php.

Comment: Eu acho que deveria ser fechada por "duplicada" e não "fora de escopo".

Comment: Se for duplicata (realmente tiver um igual), eu acho beleza fechar. Eu procurei, mas só achei com utilização de linguagens que eu não conheço. Vou dar uma olhada nesse link seu.

Comment: @Inkeliz , me falaram que não é certo armazenar imagens no banco de dados. Você concorda com isso ?

Comment: Pelo que entendi, o conteúdo da imagem está armazenada no banco. É considerado mais adequado armazenar o caminho do arquivo no servidor. Mas dá para usar dessa forma, não precisa de ajax, basta definir um arquivo php como src da imagem e neste arquivo setar um cabeçalho para indicar que é uma imagem: header('Content-type: image/jpeg'); e dar um echo no conteúdo da imagem oriundo do banco de dados.

Comment: Acho que pode ajudar: [Problema ao exibir imagem entre tags html](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/372327/3774)

Comment: Obrigado, @Inkeliz e Icaro Martins. A ajuda de vocês foram ótimas. Os links de vocês resolveram meu problema.